# How to change font size for all rows in a list using JSON on SP Online via Format View

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting

I know that I can format each column view by "Format This Column" but is there a way to format the whole list in the same manner? In particular, increasing the font size or any of the font attributes by using JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to format the whole list view, I suggest you use View Formatting to achieve it.

The following article with the example code for your reference.

[sp-dev-list-formatting-view-samples](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-list-formatting/tree/master/view-samples)

If you only want to increasing the font size, we can use the following JSON formatting to achieve it.

```
{
  "schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "additionalRowClass": "sp-field-fontSize24"
}
```

And we can use the following Class to adjust the font size.

sp-field-fontSize14

sp-field-fontSize15

sp-field-fontSize17

sp-field-fontSize21

sp-field-fontSize24

sp-field-fontSize28

sp-field-fontSize32

sp-field-fontSize36

sp-field-fontSize42

Comment: LZ_MSFT that is a great resource and was one of the first places I found searching but none of the examples gave reference to changing the font size for all of the rows all together. Thank you just the same. Would you know how to make all text in a table , list, all the rows change font size via JSON?

Comment: Thanks LZ bought me to the right place.
For others looking: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/formatting-list-views-f737fb8b-afb7-45b9-b9b5-4505d4427dd1